What value should I set for `<customAttributeName>` when setting up Amazon Cognito for federated authentication using Azure AD?
I'm following this document to set up Amazon Cognito for federated authentication using Azure AD.
One thing that I don't understand is <customAttributeName> in step 3 in that document.
What should I put in <customAttributeName>? Can I name it with whatever value I like?
I've tried setting <customAttributeName> to azure_ad_connection. But then I got redirected to https://my-call-back-url.mydomain.com/index.html?error_description=Invalid+SAML+response+received%3A+Invalid+user+attributes%3A+The+attribute+azure_ad_connection+is+not+defined+in+schema.+&error=server_error when I login Cognito through its Hosted UI.
The address contains an error message saying The attribute azure_ad_connection is not defined in schema. So obviously <customAttributeName> is not a value that can be arbitrarily set.
What value should I set for <customAttributeName>?
